# show details about first chance exceptions without breaking

Tags: exception, windbg

Using WindDbg I would like to print details about first chance CLR exceptions (`!ClrStack, !PrintException`) when they occur but keep the debugee running normally. How can I set this up?

This was my best bet, but it doesn't do anything:

```
sx- -c "!CLRStack"
sxe CLR "!CLRStack;g"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
sxe -c "!pe;!clrstack;gc" clr
```